# Tiling problem : tiling square allowing space.

Tags: combinatorics, tiling

Given we have a 4 by 4 square and we place 2 by 1 tiles until we can not place it anymore without overlapping. For example, if $1$ denotes the tile and $0$ means the empty space, the tiling below is valid.

```
0110
1111
1111
0110
```

It is also a valid tiling to fill all space of the square.
Then is there any way to enumerate all possible tiling?

Comment: If by "enumerate" you mean to give all the tilings, I can't see how to do it besides make all the examples and show others impossible. But if by enumerate you just mean find out how many such tilings there are (without making them), then there may be but it would be difficult I believe.

Comment: It's not necessary to show all tilings. I was just thinking that it's impossible to have a closed form of the number of possible tilings without enumerating them in reasonable way.

Comment: The number of tilings is finite, so hard to see what you mean by "closed form".

Comment: This seems like an interesting thing to just get how many such tilings with no more possible 2 by 1. [+1 on question though I haven't thought how to do it...]

Comment: So you want to count the number of tilings using dominoes and monominoes with the restriction that no two monominoes are adjacent to each other. There probably is no method for counting them other than essentially going all possibilities. You could find all the ways to cover the central 2x2, and examine each of those cases. You could make use of symmetries to reduce the number of cases to check, but it would still be a lot of case work.

Answer (score 0):

We can describe this problem as a SAT instance: we have a variable for every possible domino position and for each cell of the grid. Then we have the following clauses:

- If a domino position variable is true, then the two corresponding cells are on.
- If two dominoes intersect, they aren't both present.
- For every domino position, the two cells in that position aren't both empty.
- If a cell is on, then at least one of the covering dominoes is.

Feeding these clauses to a SAT solver, we can quickly check with a program that there are exactly [$400$](https://pastebin.com/1SJe4Pm8) solutions, [$106$](https://pastebin.com/MAa46KHF) if we treat equivalent final shapes as the same, or [$19$](https://pastebin.com/gwKyVR9q) if we also treat rotated and reflected solutions as equivalent. (Each link is to a text file with the solutions listed.)